# What does it take to get out of beta?

Tags: discussion, support, beta

This is the first beta StackExchange site i've really participated in.  What does it require to get out of beta and become a full fledged StackExchange site?  Does anything change when we move out of beta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the answer is... it depends: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/

Or, normally around 90 days?

FYI.. our stats are here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint-overflow

Answer (score 0):

The stats are going to look odd as it was migrated from the old StackOverflow system. One should note that [9 folks have yearling badges](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/badges/52/yearling).

Weasel words: I'm still bummed that I won't get a beta badge (and neither will anyone else).